# How to create a dynamic function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a simple savings system and i have already set a simple function to calculate interest. The problem is the interest rate formula. Once the app will be deployed, the formula cannot be changed anymore. My plan is to store my formula in a database and retrive the formula everytime the interest function is called but the function treats the formula as string.

Is there any way to change how a function would work during runtime?

Comment: Try to use one of the many [formula parsers/expression evaluators](http://csharpeval.codeplex.com/) out there.

Comment: i think it's only for c# and not for .net. But tnx for the info anyway.

Comment: @BryanwendellGabin - You certainly could use a c# parser in your VB.Net application. It's all .Net.

Comment: I managed to find some formula parser for vb.net as well. I'll try to integrate it to my system.. Tnx for all the help!!